# NullPointerException while sorting XML using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, sorting, jdom

I have a String formatted as XML and trying to sort it. I thought of creating an XML file from String and then sort the xml file itself.

I am using [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) library to try to sort the XML. I have created a JDOM document from the string and am trying to use comparator based on attribute as key but am getting NullPointerException on comparing. Below is the code:

```
File xmlFile = new File(filePath);

SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
org.jdom2.Document document = null;
try {
    document = (org.jdom2.Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
} catch (JDOMException e1) {
    System.out.println(Constants.JDOM_ERROR+e1.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.println(Constants.IO_EXCEPTION+e1.getMessage());
}

org.jdom2.Element rootElement = document.detachRootElement();
List<org.jdom2.Element> children = new ArrayList<org.jdom2.Element>(rootElement.getChildren());
rootElement.removeContent();

Comparator<org.jdom2.Element> comparator = new Comparator<org.jdom2.Element>() {
    public int compare(org.jdom2.Element o1, org.jdom2.Element o2) {
        return o2.getAttributeValue(key).compareTo(o1.getAttributeValue(key));
    }
};
Collections.sort(children, comparator);

org.jdom2.Document newDocument = new org.jdom2.Document(rootElement);
rootElement.addContent(children);

XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
try {
    xmlOutput.output(newDocument, new FileWriter("sorted.xml"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(Constants.IO_EXCEPTION+e.getMessage());
}
```

This line throws the exception:

```
return o2.getAttributeValue(key).compareTo(o1.getAttributeValue(key));
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
  at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:230)
  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
  at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
  at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

Am not able to understand whats wrong. Please help.

Comment: Its not duplicate. I am facing problem in sorting XML.

Comment: Your `children` list seems to contain `null`s. TimSort, as far as I remember, is not null-tolerant by default. If you want null-tolerance, then your comparator *must* respect `null`s itself: 
`if ( o1 == null && o2 == null ) { return 0; } if ( o1 == null ) { return /*- */-1; } if ( o2 == null ) { return /*- */+1; } return ... your stuff here ...;`.

Comment: @Jens roger_that is right: it's not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Jens, Oh I'm very sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: It is full stack trace or there is something else?